# How to block keyboard, mouse and touch input?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am using the `BlockInput()` function (`winuser.h`) to block keyboard, mouse, and touch input, but I am not able to block the touchpad in new versions of Windows.

How can I resolve my problem?

Can you share your code that can solve my problem, or guide me to a solution?

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // Block input
    if (BlockInput(TRUE)) {
        std::cout << "Input blocked." << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Failed to block input." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Wait for 10 seconds
    Sleep(10000);

    // Unblock input
    if (BlockInput(FALSE)) {
        std::cout << "Input unblocked." << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Failed to unblock input." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your Windows Messaging loop, have you tried receiving messages from those entities, and marking the message as "processed" without doing anything?  This is basically ignoring those messages.

Comment: The [`BlockInput()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-blockinput) only mentions keyboard and mouse, it says nothing about touch. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51018724/65863) suggests you can use a `SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL)` hook to detect touch input. Such hooks can dismiss input from being processed.

Comment: Duplicates: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19315527/how-to-disable-touch-screen-in-windows-8), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270057/whats-the-windows-api-for-disabling-finger-input), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066192/programmatically-enable-disable-multitouch-finger-input)

Comment: @RemyLebeau A `WH_MOUSE_LL` hook doesn't detect touch input (and cannot block it). It detects mouse input, including mouse input generated from touch input for compatibility. The linked answer merely identifies synthesized compatibility mouse input events.

Comment: @RemyLebeau  SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, MouseProc, NULL, 0) can be used; I implemented this.
but it has one limitation: it cannot block three-finger shortcuts.
Can you suggest some solutions for that?